# $(x^2-a)(x^2-b)(x^2-ab)$ ≡ 0 (mod p)$ is solvable.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Let p be an odd prime and let a,b ∈ Z such that p ∤ a. Prove that the congruence $(x^2-a)(x^2-b)(x^2-ab)$ ≡ 0 (mod p) is always solvable.

Not sure where to begin here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ mod $p,\ $ if $\,a,b\,$ are not quadratic residues [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32991/242) $\,ab\,$ is one, i.e. if $\,x^2-a,\,x^2-b\,$ have no roots, then $\,x^2-ab\,$ has a root.

Comment: is this a therorem?

Comment: Also, I do not believe I have this as a theorem to use, otherwise I would have to prove it while im not sure as how to do so.

Comment: @Jonathan This is one of the first theorems one learns when studying quadratic reciprocity. It is highly unlikely that this problem would be posed before that result was proven.